# Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.14.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'

Tags: flutter

Sorry for my English.

I'm trying to use `_scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>` in my project.
But Visual Code says about problem for it:

"

```
This requires the 'constructor-tearoffs' language feature to be enabled.
Try updating your pubspec.yaml to set the minimum SDK constraint to 2.14.0 or higher, and running 'pub get'.
```

"

In my pubspec.yaml I have same line:

```
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
```

when in terminal i'm run "dart --version" it says:

```
Dart SDK version: 2.14.4 (stable) (Wed Oct 13 11:11:32 2021 +0200) on "windows_x64"
```

Why Visual Code generate error? How to resolve it?
Command "flutter pub get" havn't result.

Comment: Did you miss the parentheses for the contructor?

Comment: Yes, I'm... *falcepalm* Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try these, it may solve your problem

1. In terminal run

   flutter clean

   flutter pub get

   flutter pub upgrade

if the above command not worked then try,

```
   flutter pub cache repair
```

Comment: havn't good result. error is staying after all that. when I run "flutter pub get" I saw same line in terminal "flutter 0.0.0 from sdk flutter" can be that source of problem?

Comment: "flutter doctor -v" print "Dart version 2.14.4" but Visual Studio Code anyway generate error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that just not correct error from IDE when I used not correct code.

If write code like `final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();` it's work with no errors!

Thx!